# CSS Divs Sit on top of each other when i resize window / Bootstrap columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem, I have a calendar on the left side and a table on the right, and when I resize them the table goes on top of the calendar. But if I only have two tables they are not going to the top of each other. I am using bootstrap columns. 
My HTML and CSS:

http://www.codeply.com/go/PuSjxAdpfM

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="jquery-calendar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">

            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <div class="div-table-head">Tabela de exemplo</div>
                <tr>
                    <th>Início</th>
                    <th>Fím</th>
                    <th>Consulta</th>
                    <th>T</th>
                    <th>M</th>
                    <th>L</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>Consulta Abe</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>Consulta Abe</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>12:00</td>
                        <td>Consulta Abe</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.picker-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
.cal {

  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 216px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.cal tr, .cal th, .cal td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.cal caption {
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px black;
  background: #333;
  /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);*/
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #313131;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}
.cal caption a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #e2e2e2;
}
.cal caption a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.cal caption .prev {
  float: left;
}
.cal caption .next {
  float: right;
}
.cal th, .cal td {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.cal th:first-child, .cal td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
.cal th {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #696969;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-left: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
}
.cal td {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}
.cal td a {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #666;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea, #e5e5e5 60%, #d9d9d9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea, #e5e5e5 60%, #d9d9d9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea, #e5e5e5 60%, #d9d9d9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea, #e5e5e5 60%, #d9d9d9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.cal td a:hover, .cal td.off a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.cal td.off a {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
.cal td.active a, .cal td a:active {
  margin: -1px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #00A99D;
  border: 1px solid #598b94;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.cal td.active:first-child a, .cal td:first-child a:active {
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.cal td.active:last-child a, .cal td:last-child a:active {
  border-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.cal tr:last-child td.active a, .cal tr:last-child td a:active {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem relies on your calendar having a fixed width, which on small screens gets to be smaller than the `col-xs-2` bootstrap column. Anyways, as @Paulie_D said, you should include your code in your question in case the link falls so that others can benefit from this question in the future too.

Comment: @pablito.aven i post the css and html. thanks for the fast reply. but if i do like width: 100% or remove the width its the same :/

Comment: Perhaps you could modify your bootstrap columns to a bigger one, `col-xs-4` and `col-xs-8`  intead of 2 and 10. Or something like that. Even tho, I think you could do this without bootstrap, if it's not going to be responsive, why use a responsive-columns layout ?

Comment: But if i use bigger one like you say the columns stay with large white space on the calendar. You can test on codeply.  Im using responsive columns because i need to see on the mobile or smaller monitor. thanks @pablito.aven